# When I joined multiple tables in ruby on rails I got Error : "uninitialized constant OfferLetter::Users"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ruby on rails,I want to joined multiple tables and extract data and print.I am posting my code...

this is my hr_controller.rb

```
@employees = OfferLetter.joins(:users, :user_details, :clients)
```

these are models
"user.rb"

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base has_many :offer_letter  end
```

"offer_letter.rb"

```
class OfferLetter < ActiveRecord::Base  belongs_to :users end
```

"client,rb"

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :user end
```

"user_details.rb"

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :user end
```

here

- "users table (id, email, first_name, last_name)"
- "user_details table (user_id, contact_number, gender)"
- "clients table (user_id,company_name)"
- "offer_letters(candidate_id,client_id,created_by_id,ctc,cliend_address)"
- here (id = user_id) in user and user_details and clients
- (user_id = client_id) in clients and offer_letter
- (candidate_id = id, created_by_id = id) in users and offerletter tables.
- **I want to print first_name, last_name, contact_number, gender, ctc, cliend_address, compnay_name etc **

Comment: try this, @employees = User.includes(:user_details, :clients, :offer_letters)

Answer (score 0):

In `user.rb`, you need to pluralize `offer_letter`

```
has_many :offer_letters
```

In `offer_letter.rb` you need to singularize `users`

```
belongs_to :user
```

The query should be

```
@employees = OfferLetter.joins(user: [:user_details, :clients])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: when I wrote above statement then I got following error "Association named 'user_details' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?" div id="job_details">
       <% @employees.each do |emp| %>
     <%= render partial: "hr/employee_details", locals: {emp: emp} %>
    <% end %>       
      </div> please tell me where am i wrong ?????

Comment: user_details belongs to user, So in user.rb you need to add has_many :user_details

Comment: I wrote exactly but I got Error : Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'offer_letters.user_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `offer_letters`.* FROM `offer_letters` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `offer_letters`.`user_id` INNER JOIN `user_details` ON `user_details`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `client_recruiters` ON `client_recruiters`.`recruiter_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` `clients_users` ON `clients_users`.`id` = `client_recruiters`.`client_id` AND `clients_users`.`type` IN ('UserClient')

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
has_many :<plural form>
belongs_to :<singular form>
```

for example:

```
class OfferLetter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offer_letters
end
```